Sony ToFAR: Coexistence of ToFARToFManager and XR Origin's main camera
I am currently trying to implement a simple Unity app for obstacle detection using iPhone PointCloud data obtained by ToFAR.
In addition to ToF AR, I have implemented AR display content and originally implemented XR Origin.
So, when I set ToFARToFManager to obtain PointCloud data and XR Origin in the Unity hierarchy, the smartphone camera images that had been displayed up until now turned black, and it became impossible to display camera images in the background.
Is it possible to set ToFARToFManager and XR Origin at the same time?
If there is a workaround, please let me know.

You can use ToF AR and ToF XR Origin (ARFoundation) simultaneously by using the ARFoundationConnector included in ToF AR.
Please refer to the following for the explanation of ARFoundationConnector.
https://tof-ar.com/files/2/tofar/manual_reference/ToF_AR_User_Manual_en.html#_arfoundationconnector

Thank you.
Why do I have to use this Connector?
I don't really understand the ARFoundation specifications, but is it possible to access a single ARCameraManager (or AROcclusionManager) defined somewhere from multiple sources?

This is because both ARFoundation and ToF AR occupy the camera when in use, so they cannot be used simultaneously. ToF AR can obtain data output from ARFoundation without occupying the camera by using the ARFoundationConnector, allowing both ARFoundation and ToF AR functionalities to be used simultaneously. For more details, please refer to the link below:
https://tof-ar.com/files/2/tofar/manual_reference/ToF_AR_Reference_Articles_en.html#_arfoundationconnector

And the ARFoundationConnector prefab already includes ARCameraManager and AROcclusionManager, so it is possible to reference and use them from the application as well.

Thank you for your reply. I understand.
By the way, I understand that ToF AR can obtain information up to a depth of 5m, but is this the limit of the distance that can be detected?
Or is it possible to detect even further, and is this intentionally limited? (Perhaps due to accuracy issues?)

The limitation of a 5-meter distance for ToF AR is intentionally imposed, not due to the actual distance capability.
ToF AR can handle depth values up to a maximum of 16 bits (approximately 65m).
However, the actual distance that can be captured depends on the device, ranging system, and OS.
For example, it is 16 bits on iOS, but when using the DEPTH16 format on Android, it becomes 13 bits (approximately 8m).

The distance range of devices that use lasers is determined by the power of the laser.
Smartphones and other mobile devices are limited to the safest and the lowest Class 1 output.
Depending on the method, they can range from a few meters to more than 10 meters.
